# Let $\mathcal S$ be the collection of all straight lines in the plane $\mathbb R^2$. If $\mathcal S$ is a subbasis for a topology ...

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal S$ be the collection of all straight lines in the plane $\mathbb R^2$. If $\mathcal S$ is a subbasis for a topology $\mathcal T$ on the set $\mathbb R^2$, what is the topology?

I know that the topology must be the discrete topology, but I can't seem to think how I can go about showing it. I tried searching online and came across this (see picture below), but something does not seem correct about it:

[image]

The above screenshot was taken from [here](https://michaeltdeguzman.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/topohw32.pdf).

The reason I feel that this is not correct, is because they use the fact that the point $(a,b)$ is open. However, $\mathbb R^2$ is Hausdorff, and so singleton sets (i.e points) are closed?

Is there any other way that I can go about proving this?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ is Hausdorff with the standard topology. We are imposing a new topology generated by $\mathcal S$, thus it need not be Hausdorff.

Comment: @TrevorNorton . That makes sense :). Thanks! But how can we conclude that the point $(a,b)$ is in fact open in the topology generated by $\mathcal S$?

Comment: Every set in the subbasis is open, and any finite intersection of sets from the subbasis is also open. Since we can pick two lines whose only intersection is a single point (say $x=a$ and $y=b$), we can say that the single point is also open.

Comment: Actually, this new topology is also Hausdorff ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen . Does the argument given by Trevor above still hold though in showing that the point $(a,b)$ is open?

Comment: @user290425 Of course, see also the meanwhile existing answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\mathscr T$ be a topology on a non-empty set $X$ and let $\mathscr S\subseteq \mathscr T$. Then, **by definition**, $\mathscr S$ is a *subbasis* for the topology $\mathscr T$ if for any $U\subseteq X$, one has that $U\in\mathscr T$ if and only if $U$ can be expressed as a union of sets which are finite intersections from sets in $\mathscr S$. Formally: $$U=\bigcup_{\gamma\in\Gamma}\bigcap_{i\in F_{\gamma}} S_i^{\gamma},$$ where

- $\Gamma$ is an (arbitrary) index set,
- for each $\gamma\in\Gamma$, $F_{\gamma}$ is a *finite* index set, and
- for each $\gamma\in\Gamma$ and $i\in F_{\gamma}$, it holds that $S_i^{\gamma}\in\mathscr S$.

---

In the concrete example, note that any set consisting of a single point in $\mathbb R^2$ can be expressed as the intersection of two lines, which lines are in $\mathscr S$ by assumption (in this case, the index set $\Gamma$ has a single element $\gamma$, and the index set $F_{\gamma}$ has two elements, corresponding to the two lines). This implies that every one-point set in $\mathbb R^2$ is open according to this new topology $\mathscr T$, so that $\mathscr T$, in fact, must be the discrete topology (in which *every* subset is open).

---

In the light of your question:

> However, $\mathbb R^2$ is Hausdorff, and so singleton sets (i.e points) are closed?

Two comments: Firstly, the new topology $\mathscr T$ is different from the standard Euclidean topology. This is a common source of confusion, since we are so used to working with the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R^2$ that we have a strange feeling upon seeing that nothing prevents us from defining any other topology on $\mathbb R^2$. Therefore, that the Euclidean topology is Hausdorff does not say anything about whether the discrete topology $\mathscr T$ is Hausdorff or not.

That said, secondly, the discrete topology on $\mathbb R^2$ does happen to be Hausdorff, so that it is also $T_1$ (*i.e.*, the singletons are closed). This is compatible with the fact that singleton sets are open in the discrete topology, since any subset of the space is both open *and closed* under this topology.